# Possible to make re.finditer() exclude delimiters from groups?

Tags: python, regex, parsing

My task is to convert a "source" text into a sequence of elements: `TEXT` and `INPUT`. `INPUT` are those parts wrapped into two astericks, while TEXT is everything else.

Here is an example:

```
>>> source = 'I came *across* these old photos when I *was* tidying the closet.'
>>> parse(source)
TEXT: 'I came '
INPUT: 'across'
TEXT: ' these old photos when I '
INPUT: 'was'
TEXT: ' tidying the closet.'
```

The purpose of such parsing is to create a "fill-in-the-gap" interactive tool for language training. The parsed elements will eventually go to the client side, where `TEXT` elements are displayed "as is", while `INPUT` elements are displayed as input fields for the user to type into.

To achieve this I have slightly modified the example given in [Writing a Tokenizer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#writing-a-tokenizer) section of the `re`library documentation. Here is my solution:

```
def parse(text):
    token_specifications = [
        ('INPUT', r'(\*\w\*)|(\*\w+[^*]*\w+\*)'),
        ('TEXT', r'[^*]+'),
    ]
    token_regex = '|'.join('(?P<%s>%s)' % pair for pair in token_specifications)
    elements = []
    for mo in re.finditer(token_regex, text):
        kind = mo.lastgroup
        value = mo.group()
        # A hack to remove the delimiters
        if kind == 'INPUT':
            value = value.replace('*', '')
        print("%s: '%s'" % (kind, value))
        elements.append((kind, value))
    # Testing the result
    if elements != [
        ('INPUT', 'This'),
        ('TEXT', ' is '),
        ('INPUT', 'a'),
        ('TEXT', ' text that '),
        ('INPUT', 'needs to be'),
        ('TEXT', ' parsed. '),
        ('INPUT', 'Highlighted'),
        ('TEXT', ' elements must be in '),
        ('INPUT', 'INPUT'),
        ('TEXT', ' group.'),
    ]:
        raise Exception("Parsing result is wrong!")

text = '*This* is *a* text that *needs to be* parsed. *Highlighted* elements must be in *INPUT* group.'
parse(text)
```

It works as expected, and looks neat enough, except for one small issue. Namely, the `INPUT` elements come together with astericks, and I have to explicitly strip them off (see `A hack to remove the delimiters` part of the code).

Is there a way to make `finditer()` function throw the delimiters away, so I don't have to do it explicitly?

Also, if there are any other tips to make my code more elegant, they are more than welcome.

Comment: Try running this: `print(‘*hi*’.strip(‘*’))` I didn’t take a super in depth look at your code, but couldn’t capturing groups be used for this?

Comment: There is always that thing about which side of  input to designate as text on a per pair basis. The best way to do this is to use a single regex in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify your `REGEX` and your `code`:

```
text = '*This* is *a* text that *needs to be* parsed. *Highlighted* elements must be in *INPUT* group.'
elements = []
token_specifications = [
    ('INPUT', r'\*(?P<{}>\w+(?:[^*]\w+)*)\*'),
    ('TEXT', r'(?P<{}>[^*]+)'),
    ]
token_regex = '|'.join(exp.format(k) for k, exp in token_specifications)
# for match in re.finditer(r'\*(?P<INPUT>[^*]+)\*|(?P<TEXT>[^*]+)', text):
for match in re.finditer(token_regex, text):
    kind = match.lastgroup
    value = match.group(kind)
    elements.append((kind, value))

print(elements)
# [('INPUT', 'This'), ('TEXT', ' is '), ('INPUT', 'a'), ('TEXT', ' text that '), ('INPUT', 'needs to be'),
# ('TEXT', ' parsed. '), ('INPUT', 'Highlighted'), ('TEXT', ' elements must be in '), ('INPUT', 'INPUT'), ('TEXT', ' group.')]
```

I combined your `INPUT` regex like this `\*(\w+(?:[^*]*\w+)*)\*` with one capturing group that don't include `*`. and you get the captured group by name like this: `match.group('NAME_OF_GROUP')`

Comment: Python capture group name might reject `{}`

Comment: Awesome, thank you very much! I didn't know about non-capturing groups, and overall my regex kung-fu level is not enough to invent such solution by myself. Yet I learned something new today! :)

Comment: @x15 I used it to format the name of the group in the next line.